# Dynamic number of columns to display using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, angular7, dynamic-columns

We are using angular 7 in front end and spring boot at the backend. As per the requirement we need to display dynamic number of columns in the front end, which can vary from 10 to 52 columns depending on data returned from database. 
IS there a solution for this apart from creating a object with max expected number of columns. Alos, screen will have tree structure so we are planning to use mat-tree in angular end was thinking of using TreeNode from java for backend. Any help is appricated.

[Expected Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKdss.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create several objects. If data is in an array, use *ngFor in the row where dynamic data starts.